# Solspace Calendar: Showing future events - date_range_start parameter not working

Tags: solspace-calendar

I want to show future events based on today.

I currently have 3 dummy events in my system, 1 past, 1 today, 1 future. When I run the code below no events show up:

```
{exp:calendar:events event_limit="3" status="open" date_range_start="today" orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc"}
```

If I take out the parameter:

```
date_range_start="today"
```

Then all appear.

I'm running the same query for past events using:

```
date_range_end="yesterday"
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The tag you're very likely looking for is **`{exp:calendar:cal}`**, not `{exp:calendar:events}`. This is almost always the tag to use when displaying **upcoming/future events** (or past events, or events within a specific timeframe) is the goal.

**`{exp:calendar:cal}`** is the only tag that creates a truly chronological list of events and respects the time/date window set in `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` (i.e. it looks for events/occurrences within the set timeframe).

(**Note**: add `pad_short_weeks="n"` as well to `{exp:calendar:cal}` to avoid it from adding extra days in your timeframe to complete a calendar "week row")

The following documentation page, which explains in more details why/when each of the main Calendar tags are used, is a strongly recommended read: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I updated my "upcoming events" code to use cal which is now working, thank you. However when I add the parameter pad_short_weeks="n" it fails to return any results so I have removed this. Secondly I don't see a way of ordering results, does this mean that the results are automatically chronological? Thirdly if I use cal for the "past events" it returns future events, I'm updating the parameters to provide only a date_range_end="today". I presume this means cal is only used to retrieve future events ??

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the events documentation. Notice how the [date range end parameter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#date_range_end). Defaults to today. You just need to specify a date range end for the events tag to be used this way.